# another way to pop to root viewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have `navigationBar` with this [side menu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)
I and I want add `Button` when I pressed go to root view controller
I tried using all of this

```
presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)


let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count ], animated: true);
```

please if anyone can try download the example and tell me what the wrong and what I should do

this is my main storybord
[image]

I want to pop this viewcontrller or any numbers of viewControllrs above it using sideMenu class
[image]

side menuclass is table, so I use this method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
some cell if user press it, it should pop all views above main views
this way work well with push, but pop No

Comment: @NDoc here my storyboard https://s21.postimg.io/6qsqc35w7/Screen_Shot_1437_11_24_at_3_43_29_PM.png

Comment: Can you add the flow of your viewController's in question and show us from which controller you want to pop to root.

Comment: @NDoc the selected view is main viewcontroller and the root and I do push to views from sideMenu programmatically not like example from storyboard

Comment: You have two `NavigationController`, so try like this `self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)`

Comment: @NDoc this is not work :( If this is possible, can I send it to you to see it? i spent a lot of time without any solution :(